# As3: How do I get my projectile to arc and go back down?

Tags: actionscript-3, physics

My projectile begins to arc but then moves to the right uncontrollably and does not ever go down.
I don't know what's wrong.

Here's my initial variables

```
private var gravity:Number = 9.8;
private var xVelocity:Number = 30;
private var yVelocity:Number = 30;
private var speedx:Number = xVelocity*Math.cos(Math.PI/180);
private var speedy:Number = yVelocity*Math.sin(Math.PI/180);
```

This is how the bullet is moved (continually done after creaton)

```
bullet.x += speedx/10;
bullet.y -= speedy;
speedy -= gravity/10;
```

And this is how the bullet is added to the screen

```
bullet.x = (player.getX() +(Math.cos((player.getRotation()+90)*Math.PI/180)));
bullet.y = (player.getY()+(Math.sin((player.getRotation()+90)*Math.PI/180)));
```

Comment: Something is seriously wrong here. In the last part ("the bullet is added to the screen") you change the location of the bullet with no regard to its previous location. Unless you're moving the player in some funny way, I can't imagine how you're getting even the beginning of a realistic arc.

Comment: That's the original location of the bullet. Sorry for the confusion. That part is actually running first. Essentially the player is a circle spinning around it's center, and it shoots off the bullets in the direction it's facing.

Comment: Then the code looks basically correct (apart from some harmless peculiarities like `speed` vs. `velocity`). Can you take a look at `speedy` and verify that it decreases steadily? It should start at zero and after 20 iterations it should be about -19.

Comment: Wait a second... Are you sure you've got the coordinates straight? Is it possible that "up" is actually +x and "right" is actually +y?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here. I think you've got your coordinates mixed up: your "up" is actually `+x` and your "right" is actually `+y`. So the bullet starts out moving in the `+x` direction, and keeps moving in `+x` ("up") while falling faster and faster toward `+y` ("right"). And it's falling toward `+y` and not `-y` because that's the way you've defined things-- you have one more `-` in there than you probably intended.

Switch your coordinates around, and things should look realistic.